# Strange Data Task Error (Function, Completion Block) iOS 10, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm having some issues with a function call:

```
 static func fromDictionary(dictionary: NSDictionary) -> Business? {

    //Pull out each individual element from the dictionary
    guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String,
        let rating = dictionary["rating"] as? Double,
        let reviewCount = dictionary["review_count"] as? Int,
        let imageUrl = dictionary["image_url"] as? String,
        let url = dictionary["url"] as? String
        else {
            print("Error creating object from dictionary")
            return nil
    }


    //create location
    guard let locationDictionary = dictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
    guard let locationObject = Location.fromDictionary(dictionary: locationDictionary) else {return nil}

    //create coordinates
    guard let coordinatesDictionary = dictionary["coordinates"] as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
    guard let latitude = coordinatesDictionary["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees else { return nil }
    guard let longitude = coordinatesDictionary["longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees else { return nil  }
    let coordinatesObject = CLLocation(latitude: latitude , longitude: longitude)

    //Take the data parsed and create a Place Object from it
    return Business(name: name, id: id, location: locationObject, coordinates: coordinatesObject, rating: rating, reviewCount: reviewCount, imageUrl: imageUrl, url: url)
}
```

here is the function in a completion block

```
... do {
            let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:
                JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)

            guard let result = jsonObject as? NSDictionary else { print("result is not a dictionary"); return }
            guard let total = result["total"] as? Int else { print("no total available"); return }
            guard total > 0 else { print("Search returned 0 results") ; return }
            guard let businesses = result["businesses"] as? NSArray else { print("business is not an array"); return }

                for businessObject in businesses {
                    guard let businessDictionary = businessObject as? NSDictionary else { print("businessDict is not a dictionary"); return }

                    // create business object
                    guard let business = Business.fromDictionary(dictionary: businessDictionary) else { print("can't create a business out of the data"); return }

                    arrayOfBusinesses.append(business)

                }
            completionHandler(arrayOfBusinesses)

            } catch {
            print("Could not get places")
            return
            }

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false


    }

    //resume dataTask
    dataTask.resume()

    return

}
```

}

I've run this with breaks and notice that there are values in each step and in each variable, but for some reason I get an error in the class function

"can't create a business out of the data"

I've run the code stepwise and can't find out why the completion handler is not being called. Why is this giving an error?

I can provide additional code if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: updated the print statements and narrowed down to the latitude line.

Comment: going through stepwise with breaks shows values in latitude and longitude but still gives error after a few loops

Comment: looks like yelp returns "null" values in lat/long sometimes.

Comment: Is your `fromDictionary(dictionary: NSDictionary)` a method inside your `Business` class? If so, try moving that to your controller class where you're getting your data. And / Or... change `return Business(name: name, id: id ...)` to `let tmpBus =  Business(name: name, id: id ...)` and the `return tmpBus` -- then step through in debug and make sure `tmpBus` is a valid object as you expect.